# jQuery each and indexing elements

Tags: jquery, indexing, each

So I'm trying to get the number of the li that I click and show the corresponding page text while hiding the others. (labeled #text1, #text2, #text3 etc...),
but the code below isn't doing anything for me.

Help is greatly appreciated!

```
var j = 0;
$(".gallery li").each(function () {
    j++;

    $(".gallery li").click(function () {
        var num = $(this).index() + 1;
        $('#text' + num).addClass('currentpage');
        $('#text' + num).siblings().removeClass('currentpage');
    });
});
```

Comment: You don't need the `each`, the click event will already be attached to each li.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/Byaun/). You just need to take out the `.each`

```
$(".gallery li").click(function () {
    var num = $(this).index() + 1;
    $('#text' + num).addClass('currentpage');
    $('#text' + num).siblings().removeClass('currentpage');
});
```

Comment: Like the others said, you don't need `$('#text' + num)` or `$('#text' + num)`, it could just be `$(this)`

Comment: Well, I might be wrong, but from the OPs description, #text1, etc., are elsewhere on the page, so $(this) can't be used.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var num = $('li').index(this) + 1;
```

instead of

```
var num = $(this).index() + 1;
```

**And remove the each loop**

```
$(".gallery li").click(function () {
     var num = $('.gallery li').index(this) + 1;
     $('#text' + num).addClass('currentpage');
     $('#text' + num).siblings().removeClass('currentpage');
});
```

Should be good enough

And better .. You need not use the `index` in the first place

```
$(".gallery li").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('currentpage');
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('currentpage');
});
```

You can just use the **this context** directly in your code as that corresponds to the current li that is selected.

Comment: If there are other `li` before this set, then the index will likely be incorrect won't it? (I haven't tested.) Perhaps `$('.gallery li').index(this)`

Comment: sure.. That will be a better selector... :)

Comment: The original `var num = $(this).index() + 1;` works for me in jsFiddle - I think it was just the use of `each()` that was the problem.

Comment: I think the #text1, etc., are elsewhere on the page, so we can't use $(this).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're doing... but you can do this:

Throw in `index` and `value` as the parameters of the closure for `each`. Example: `$(".gallery li").each( function(index, value){` - then you can use `index` instead of `j`